# Feeding output of LSTM layer of previous timestep to input of Dense layer of current timestep (Keras, Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to recreate a RNN whose graph is fig. 8 in [this](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=BkDB51WR-) paper by K. Yeo et al.

So far I have simply used layers as described in the Keras functional API:

```
inputs = keras.Inputs(shape=(,))

Input_Linear_1 = layers.Dense(num_neurons, activation = 'tanh')(inputs)

#merge h_t-1 and Input_Linear_1 -> Merged_Out_InLin1

Input_Linear_2 = layers.Dense(num_neurons, activation = '')(Merged_Out_InLin1)

LSTM_cell = layers.LSTM(num_LSTM_units)(Input_Linear_2)

Out_Linear_1 = layers.Dense(num_neurons, activation = 'tanh')(LSTM_cell)

Out_Linear_2 = layers.Dense(num_neurons, activation = 'softplus')(Out_Linear_1)

Softmax_OUT = layers.Dense(num_neurons, activation = 'softmax')(Out_Linear_2)
```

The part that's bugging me is described by the comment in the code; I want to use the output of the LSTM cell of the last timestep and feed it into the second layer of the DE-RNN. I have not been able to find a neat way to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the LSTM layer return_sequences=True or return_state=True ?

Comment: @BertHobe Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought that sends it to the next LSTM cell, but I need to explicitly merge the output from the LSTM cell (t-1) with the output from Input_Linear_1 (t) to create the input for Input_Linear_2 (t).

Comment: @topitofrppuccino Did you find an answer for your question? i have a very similar problem